# How are dates stored in postgres via Ecto (using Timex)?

Tags: elixir, ecto, timex

In my phoenix application, I've been using `Ecto` with `Timex` to store my dates in `postgres`. When I show results to the end user, I show days in reverse order (i.e. today is at the top of the list) and then sort results in each day chronologically.

For this to work properly, I need to apply the users timezone before processing the sort. What I've been doing (until now) is retrieve the data, converting the dates using `Timex` and then run the sorting client-side. For example, I might do something like this:

```
tz_user = Timex.Timezone.get( "Australia/Hobart", Timex.now )

captains_log = CaptainsLog.list_logs_for_user( current_user )

days = captains_log
|> Enum.map( fn (log) -> %Log{ log |
  star_date: Timex.Timezone.convert( log.star_date, tz_user ),
  end_transmission: Timex.Timezone.convert( log.end_transmission, tz_user )
} end)
|> Enum.group_by( fn ( log ) -> Timex.to_date(log.end_transmission) end )
|> Enum.sort( fn (e1, e2) ->
  { date1, _ } = e1
  { date2, _ } = e2

  Timex.compare( date1, date2 ) >= 0
end)
```

However, now I'd like to achieve this server-side. If I do something like the following:

```
select star_date at time zone 'AEST' from captains_log;
```

The date is not adjusted for my time zone (as I had assumed would be the case). For example, "8:48am" was stored in the database as "9:48pm" and appears as "11:48am" in the above select statement. `AEDT` isn't much better, the result is "10:48am".

Here's what `star_date` and `end_transmission` looks like in the schema:

```
field :star_date, Timex.Ecto.DateTime
field :end_transmission, Timex.Ecto.DateTime
```

When records are added to the database, `star_date` is set to the last `end_transmission`. `end_transmission` is typically set to `Timex.now`.

So how are dates/times stored in `postgres` by `Ecto`? Can I write a server-side query that adjusts to the desired timezone? The timezone for each user may be different, what can I pass up to `postgres` so I can make the query work for different time zones?

Comment: Sorry, "8:48am" is the desired date (AEST). The database shows it as "9:48pm" ("2018-02-28 21:48:22.896673")

Comment: What does `select star_date at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'AEST' from captains_log;` return?

Comment: That returns "10:48am"

Comment: This question was [answered](https://elixirforum.com/t/how-are-dates-stored-in-postgres-via-ecto-using-timex/12824/6?u=mitkins) on Elixir Forums. Looks like dates are stored in UTC format without timezone info. Using `::timestamptz` sets the timezone for UTC, **then** the `at time zone` syntax works

Comment: E.g. `select star_date::timestamptz at time zone ‘AEST’ from captains_log;`